# Unable to use express sessions in heroku nodejs app

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

In my app.js I have:

```
var express       = require('express')
var path          = require('path');
var logger        = require('morgan');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
var passport      = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo         = require('mongodb');
var flash         = require('connect-flash');
....
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser('3mKay'));
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'thisISmyS3cR3t'}));
```

This crashes with the following message in Heroku.

```
 Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
 at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:25:17)
 at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
 at startup (node.js:119:16)
 at node.js:906:3
```

I ran so it does exist in the package.json file as well:

```
 npm install express-sessions --save

"dependencies": {
....
"express": "~4.8.6",
"express-session": "^1.8.1",
"passport": "^0.2.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
....
```

It works fine when I comment out the

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'thisISmyS3cR3t'}));
```

And I've also tried variations of the above but it gives the same error message. Any ideas what may be causing this to happen? Something I might have overlooked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you install it, you have to actually use it in your code:

```
var express       = require('express');
var session       = require('express-session');
var path          = require('path');
var logger        = require('morgan');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
var passport      = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo         = require('mongodb');
var flash         = require('connect-flash');
....
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser('3mKay'));
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({ secret: 'thisISmyS3cR3t'}));
```

Comment: I do use it, if you look at, I say app.use(express.session()) but I tried changing it to just app.use(session()) and it gives me another error :

 Sep 13 13:56:05 lit-beach-2326 app/web.1: app.use(session({ secret: 'thisISmyS3cR3t'}));
Sep 13 13:56:05 lit-beach-2326 app/web.1:         ^
Sep 13 13:56:05 lit-beach-2326 app/web.1: ReferenceError: session is not defined

Comment: Oh I see my problem here, being that I haven't defined var sessions by itself

Comment: I was using npm install express-sessions instead of express-session which was why I was having trouble. Thanks!